# Merge two pull request into base branch, if one of the pull request requires other for passing CI checks

Tags: git, github

I am not sure what is the correct or recommended way of doing this,

Here is the situation,

I have a pull request A, where CI is failing due to some issue with test cases and eslint problems already existed in the base branch of pull request A.

Now, to fix the issue in the base branch. I created another pull request B.

I can merge pull request B to the base branch no problem,
but how to take the changes from pull request B to A for fixing CI problem.

Is it okay to merge the pull request B to A and merge the pull request A, after pull request A is already merged.

I require both the pull request to be closed and merged.

- A,B & C are branch
- a1, a2 are commits in branch A
- b1, b2 are commits in branch B
- c1, c2 are commits in branch C

Case

```
A-> a1 a2
         B-> b1 b2
         C-> c1 c2

AC-> a1 a2 c1 c2
     B-> b1 b2
     C-> c1 c2

AC-> a1 a2 c1 c2
     BC-> b1 b2 c1 c2

ABC-> a1 a2 c1 c2 b1 b2 c1 c2 or a1 a2 c1 c2 b1 b2
```

What will happen to ABC merged branch ?